# QML ListView Header and Footer Items?

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I'd like to access the header and footer items in a QML `ListView` in a manner similar to calling `currentItem` to get the current delegate instance, but I can't figure out how. I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: Any reason you can't access the [`header`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-listview.html#header-prop) and `footer` properties just as you would the `currentItem` property? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I wanted to calculate the effective height of the ListView content including dynamic headers/footers/delegates.

Answer (score 4):

You should assign header/footer items to some external reference as below:

```
Window {
  property Item listHeaderItem: null
  Component {
    id: listHeaderComponent
    Item {
      id: headerItem
      width: listView.width; height: 0
      Component.onCompleted: rootWindow.listHeaderItem = headerItem
    }
  }
  ListView {
    header: listHeaderComponent
  }}
```

Comment: This seems like a valid method, if a little inconvinient, since you need to assign the item everytime you use the ListView component. I added my answer to show the method I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the header/footer objects within a function like...

```
        if(header)
        {
            var headerItem = header.createObject(null);
            // do stuff with headerItem
            headerItem.destroy();
        }
        if(footer)
        {
            var footerItem = footer.createObject(null);
            // do stuff with footerItem
            footerItem.destroy();
        }
```